# How to highlight only one state or a province using Fusion Table Search Query?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I know how to highlight a whole country using Google's Fusion Table API. I am wondering how to  highlight a region within a given country.

This is how it works at country level, but I am looking for at Region (State / Province) Level highlighting ONLY.

```
// javascript code
var table_id = 655491;
var query = "SELECT 'kml_4326' FROM "+table_id+" WHERE 'name_0' = '"+CountryName+"';";
var option = { suppressInfoWindows: true, query };
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(table_id, option);
layer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linktoC.html?lat=33.924120&lng=-112.468101&zoom=6&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20kml_4326,name_1%20%20FROM&tableid=19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA&where=name_1%20=%20'Arizona')?

Comment: Do you have the subregion (aka county) sql query by any chance? Table   (210217) to be exact. Searching the boundaries of a county.

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linktoC.html?lat=32.610591&lng=-86.754600&zoom=8&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20'geometry'%20%20FROM&tableid=0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw&where='County%20Name'%20=%20'Autauga'